# Changing numbers to fractions in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have tried this expression for ssrs 
`=Format(Fields!width.Value, "#/###" )`

I am new to SSRS and am having trouble changing numbers to fractions.

Do I input it in the query? Or is there any way to input fractions inside a report?

Comment: SSRS does not use MySQL. I have removed the MySQL tag.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya - actually you **can** create an SSRS report that uses a **MySQL** database as the data source (as well as many other non-MS data sources).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the FORMAT function in SSRS doesn't automatically convert fractions nor is there another function to convert decimals to fractions.

There's also not a function in MySQL (nor SQL Server) to convert decimals to fractions either.

There is an SQL Server function that someone wrote to convert decimals to fractions. You might be able to convert this to use in MySQL and have your query return the fraction as an additional text string.

https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/convert-numbers-to-fractions-using-sql-server/

Comment: What if use the custom code tool in ssrs. Will that work ?

Comment: @DehavenBrown - sure, you could convert the function to use in SSRS VB. Looking at it again, I suppose it wouldn't be that hard.